# shell script to add one blank line before and after an equation or align command in latex

Tags: bash, latex

I want to write a shell script which formats a latex file in such a way that all equations and align environments are preceded and followed by a blank line. Also, the next paragraph after the equation and blank line should start with a \noindent.

I have only managed halfway the first part but it keeps adding new blank lines if I run it more than once on the same file. I only want one blank line. I do not know how to write "if the blank line is already there, do not add any new one". As for the \noindent, I don't know.

Here it is what I have written:

```
`# Check if a filename is provided
if [ "$#" -ne 1 ]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 filename"
    exit 1
fi

# Check if the file exists
if [ ! -f $1 ]; then
    echo "File $1 not found!"
    exit 1
fi

# Process the file
awk '
BEGIN {
    RS = "\n"
    ORS = "\n"
    prev_line = ""
    prev_prev_line = ""
}
{
    if ($0 ~ /\\begin\{equation\}|\\begin\{align\}/) {
        if (prev_line !~ /^$/ && prev_prev_line !~ /\\begin\{equation\}|\\begin\{align\}/) {
            print "\n" $0
        } else {
            print $0
        }
    } else if ($0 ~ /\\end\{equation\}|\\end\{align\}/) {
        if (prev_line !~ /^$/ && prev_prev_line !~ /\\end\{equation\}|\\end\{align\}/) {
            print $0 "\n"
        } else {
            print $0
        }
    } else {
        print $0
    }
    prev_prev_line = prev_line
    prev_line = $0
}' $1 > $1.tmp

# Replace the original file with the processed file
mv $1.tmp $1`
```

What I want to achieve is to get rid of these pieces of code:

```
To simplify the equation, we can assume that the perturbation of the Lagrangian displacement is proportional to a spherical harmonic function, $Y_{\ell m}(\theta,\phi)$, where $\ell$ is the degree of the harmonic and $m$ is the azimuthal order. Then, we can write:
\begin{equation}
\xi(r,\theta,\phi) = \sum_{\ell=0}^{\infty}\sum_{m=-\ell}^{\ell} \xi_{\ell m}(r) Y_{\ell m}(\theta,\phi)
\end{equation}
Substituting this expression into the equation of motion, we obtain:
\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{dr}\left(\frac{\rho r^2}{P}\frac{dc_s^2}{dr}\frac{\xi_{\ell m}}{r}\right)-\frac{\omega^2\rho r^2\xi_{\ell m}}{G} = -\frac{\rho}{P}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r^2\frac{d\Phi}{dr}\right)S_{\ell m}(r)
\end{equation}
```

because it is not very helpful when working.

I would like to get

```
To simplify the equation, we can assume that the perturbation of the Lagrangian displacement is proportional to a spherical harmonic function, $Y_{\ell m}(\theta,\phi)$, where $\ell$ is the degree of the harmonic and $m$ is the azimuthal order. Then, we can write:

\begin{equation}
\xi(r,\theta,\phi) = \sum_{\ell=0}^{\infty}\sum_{m=-\ell}^{\ell} \xi_{\ell m}(r) Y_{\ell m}(\theta,\phi)
\end{equation}

\noindent
Substituting this expression into the equation of motion, we obtain:

\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{dr}\left(\frac{\rho r^2}{P}\frac{dc_s^2}{dr}\frac{\xi_{\ell m}}{r}\right)-\frac{\omega^2\rho r^2\xi_{\ell m}}{G} = -\frac{\rho}{P}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r^2\frac{d\Phi}{dr}\right)S_{\ell m}(r)
\end{equation}
```

Comment: Please read https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/89518/36296

Comment: A small sample file embedded in the question (not a link) would make this easier to test. Good luck.

Comment: If your motivation is just about readability of the source code: place a % sign at the start of the empty line so they won't mess up the output.

Comment: I agree with @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, not blank lines as that makes every displayed formula into a paragraph which is rarely needed. Start the blank lines with `%` if they are just for code readability. Bonus, you don't need all those `\noindent` all over the place.